# React Enzyme - Testing for a Value of a Specific Prop

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

My component (`<NavItems />`):

```
<Fragment>
    <Nav>
        {items.map((item, i) => (
            <NavItem key={i} url={item} />
        ))}
    </Nav>
</Fragment>
```

In my test, I want to check whether my component, `<NavItems />`, contains a `<NavItem />` component with a specific `url` prop, say `'/login'`.

The problem is that I don't care about the value of the `key` prop and it shouldn't be part of the test.

How can this be tested?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the props you want. 
The method you're looking for is most likely [findWhere](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/findWhere.html).
Something like the next code should do the trick

```
const wrapper = shallow(<NavItems />)
const nav = wrapper.shallow()

expect(nav.findWhere(el => el.is(NavItem) && el.prop('url') === '/login').length).toEqual(1)
```

So main part here is `expect`, where you can check exactly what you want.
Don't forget to pass `items` array.

With `mount` you can avoid multiple `shallow`, but don't forget it's more **heavy** operation by memory and will render whole the react tree with lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
const wrapper = mount(<NavItems />);
expect(wrapper.find(NavItem).filterWhere((item) => {
  return item.prop('url') === '/login'
}).to.have.lengthOf(1);
```

This will also work with `shallow()`

Comment: Got an error: Method “props” is only meant to be run on a single node. 4 found instead.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Updated.